# Kurdish Font issue on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, fonts

I need to display the content on my Website in Kurdish Font.

I tried to use CSS by applying the "Ali-Samik" font.. But that didnt help.

So i tried by installing a plugin.

I am using the "Webchin Kurdish Webfonts" plugin for displaying the kurdish font on my website. However the fonts are still not displayed properly.

Has anyone faced this issue earlier. Please help.

Thanks,
Sonali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the coding of the text.. USed a decoder to decode the text and then pasted it on my wordpress site. It worked !!.. here is the conversion site..http://kurdishacademy.org/converters/ali_index.php